# Steam Error - 118 Need help fixing it.!

Tags: steam

I want to buy Skyrim before the Christmas sale ends but the steam
store keeps saying: Error Code: -118

Unable to connect to server. Server may be offline or you may not be connected to the internet.

Can someone help me I want to play Skyrim!!!!!????

Comment: The error states that their servers are down right now.  I am assuming that to many people were downloading at once.

Comment: Back up!  Now I am going to buy Starbound!

Answer (score 0):

Steam is currently down, apparently for maintenance.

According to [isitdownrightnow.com](http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/steamcommunity.com.html), it's been down for over an hour already.